# Setting multiple values dynamically

Tags: swift, optimization, imageview

I have a horizontal scroll view which contains 20 images. At the moment I have set all the images one by one and created an image view 20 times.

Something like this 20 times:

```
let imageView1 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: calculateWidth(), y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
imageView1.image = photos[0]
self.imageScrollView.addSubView(imageView1)
```

This look horrible. Can I optimize this in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an array or photos, why not just iterate through that `array` and create the `imageViews`. Something like this:

```
for photo in photos {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: calculateWidth(), y: 0, width: 60, height: 60))
    imageView.image = photo
    self.imageScrollView.addSubView(imageView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your photos using a for loop, adding the images accordingly and changing the frame with every iteration:

```
var frame = CGRect(x: calculateWidth(), y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
for photo in photos {
     let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
     imageView.image = photo
     self.imageScrollView.addSubView(imageView)

     //update frame here for the next iteration
     frame.origin.y += 60
}
```

If your coordinates follow no specific pattern, you can put them in an array and set them accordingly.

Nonetheless, depending on what you are trying to accomplish with the images, if you are trying to list these images or have them in a table or grid-like form, I suggest using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` as these reuse cells and have much better performance than just adding many images on screen.